# How would I stop a jquery method running below a certain width?

Tags: jquery

How would I make a jQuery script stop running below a certain width? I am looking for it not to run below **<768px**

Currently I have

```
(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 350) {
                jQuery('.menu-appear').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                jQuery('.menu-appear').fadeOut(200);
            }
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to test the resize function but it stopped everything working. Maybe I put it in wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the menu to fade in when the window is both above a certain width ***and*** when it is scrolled below a certain position, you may want to use [the `&&` logical operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

As in:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjg0sLy/1/)**

```
function menu() {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 350 && jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
            $('.menu-appear').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            jQuery('.menu-appear').fadeOut(200);
        }
}

jQuery(document).ready(menu);
jQuery(window).resize(menu);
jQuery(window).scroll(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
       $('.menu-appear').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      $('.menu-appear').fadeOut(200);
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  $(window).width() property over here so your script will look like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).width() > 767){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350) {
            $('.menu-appear').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.menu-appear').fadeOut(200);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```